# How to discover services using Active Directory?

Tags: .net, active-directory

I would like to add server discovery to a .Net application.  This is so that I can change the servers available for the client to talk to, without rolling out new versions of the application itself.

I work for a large organisation, and different departments may want to expose their own services.  AD seems ideal for this from an organisational point of view.

Whereabouts in AD should I store this sort of thing?  Is there a standard protocol for doing this?  It's not something I've done before.

Comment: What do you intend to store? Actually, you can store arbitrary objects. We have millions of them in our forest.

Comment: URLs of the service endpoints

Comment: You should consider using a [predefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objectClass/Category or create one and find a suitable subtree.

Comment: OK, whereabouts in the tree should I save them, and what sort of queries should I run to find them?  Bear in mind that my application will run in multiple deployments.  Ideally I'd like to be able to do a  search starting at the local department, then check for global resources as well.  Is this sort of thing possible?

Comment: You have to write more about your structure. Forest, domains, approaches. This task is really tough and has to be designed very well. For instance, I manage groups in a forest with more than 2 million entries over all. So I have to design very carefully.

Comment: What I'm really looking for is general approcahes I can apply to any structure.  Thanks

Comment: Then I would create an objectClass for it. Assign a distict DN and work with RDNs in every domain. The DN will help you locate the service in the tree and it would work transparent when you create your ldap connection with the baseDN of your domain. This is what I did in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use service connection points for this. Here's a couple links to get you started:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961722.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675764(VS.85).aspx